# Node.js - ssh2-sftp-client getting multiple files error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, sftp, ssh2-sftp-client

I use ssh2-sftp-client to get some files. If I use sftp.end(); at the end I get this error in the console:

```
{ Error: fastGet->exists->exists: No SFTP connection available
    at Object.formatError (/home/project/node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/src/utils.js:62:18)
    at SftpClient.fastGet (/home/project/node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/src/index.js:590:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'ERR_NOT_CONNECTED', custom: true } 'Error'

...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I believe is currently happening is that since you're not returning a `Promise` from your second `then()`, the third `then()` gets resolved immediately (with a value of `undefined`), which causes your connection to get terminated immediately (before your `fastGet()`s have time to finish).

To fix this, you would need to explicitly return a `Promise` from your second `then()` that only gets resolved once all of the files have been transferred. You may also want to consider rejecting that promise if at least one of the transfers fails.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Can you provide code example. Yes, in the console I can see that sftp.end(); gets excecuted before the 'Success' message ...